# Executing Raw SqlQuery in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a data table in which I want to show records from the database, I want to run a raw SQL query for this, but not able to do so. I tried using dd.sqlquery but it's not getting to a list. the error always comes when I try to run the query, it shows 'DbRawSqlquery does not contain a definition for to list'

```
public ActionResult LoadData()
    {

        using (var Ms = new DHIFeedbackEntities2())
        {
            var feedbacklist = Ms.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select [FeedbackUserName],[FeedBackUserEmailID],[FeedBackComment],[Designation],[Organization],[ContactNo],[City],[FeedBackDate] from [DHIFeedback].[dbo].[FeedBack]").ToList<FeedBack>();
                //var feedbacklist=Ms.FeedBacks.SqlQuery("select [FeedbackUserName],[FeedBackUserEmailID],[FeedBackComment],[Designation],[Organization],[ContactNo],[City],[FeedBackDate] from [DHIFeedback].[dbo].[FeedBack]").ToList<FeedBack>();
            //var feedbacklist = Ms.FeedBacks.SqlQuery("select [FeedbackUserName],[FeedBackUserEmailID],[FeedBackComment],[Designation],[Organization],[ContactNo],[City],convert(varchar,[FeedBackDate],103) as [FeedBackDate] from [DHIFeedback].[dbo].[FeedBack]").ToList<FeedBack>();
            return Json(new { data = feedbacklist }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


    }

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on("click", ".opencomment", function () {
            var mycomment = $(this).data('id');
            $('.modal-body #commentdesc').html(mycomment);
           // $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });

        $('#FeedbackDetails').DataTable({

            "processing": true,

            "ajax": {
                "url": "/ViewFeedback/LoadData",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "lengthMenu": [
                [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
                [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
            ],
            "autoWidth": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "ordering": true,
             "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){      
                      var oSettings = this.fnSettings();
                       $("td:first", nRow).html(oSettings._iDisplayStart+iDisplayIndex +1);
                       return nRow;
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": null, "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "FeedbackUserName", "name": "User Name", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "FeedBackUserEmailID", "name": "Email ID", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "FeedBackComment", "name": "Comment", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Designation", "name": "Designation", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Organization", "name": "Organization", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "ContactNo", "name": "Contact No", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "City", "name": "City", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "data": "FeedBackDate", "name": "Feedback Date", "autoWidth": true,
                    //'render': function (jsonDate) {
                    //    var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
                    //    var month = date.getMonth();
                    //    return date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                    //}
                },


            ],


            columnDefs: [{

                targets: 3,
                //data:"FeedbackID",
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    if (type === 'display' && data.length > 40) {
                       return '<span title="' + data + '">' + data.substr(0, 38) + '...<a href="" data-id="'+data+'" data-toggle="modal" class="opencomment" data-target="#myModal">Show More</a>';

                    }
                    else {
                        return data;
                    }


                }

            }],


public partial class FeedBack
{
    public int FeedbackID { get; set; }
    public string FeedbackUserName { get; set; }
    public string FeedBackUserEmailID { get; set; }
    public string FeedBackComment { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> FeedBackDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> IsPublished { get; set; }
    public string Reply { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> IsReplied { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ReplyDate { get; set; }
    public string ReplyBy { get; set; }
    public string Sector { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Status { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int January { get; set; }
    public int February { get; set; }
    public int March { get; set; }
    public int April { get; set; }
    public int May { get; set; }
    public int June { get; set; }
    public int July { get; set; }
    public int August { get; set; }
    public int September { get; set; }
    public int October { get; set; }
    public int November { get; set; }
    public int December { get; set; }
    public string Monthlyupdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Month{ get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<FeedBack> FeedBackCollection { get; set; }





}
```

Comment: `Ms.Database.SqlQuery<FeedBack>("select ........ ").ToList();` use this way...

Comment: it shows error `The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'DHIFeedbackModel.FeedBack'. A member of the type, 'FeedbackID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'
`

Comment: This question sounds to be about Entity Framework, I would suggest updating the tags.

Comment: done, can u solve my issue

Comment: Do you have `FeedbackID` in your DB table?

Comment: yes , feedbackID is present in the db table, you can check above in my code

Comment: You are missing FeedBackId in your SQL Query. As it is non nullable, it will throw an error because it requires it. Try adding FeedBackId to your SQL Query.